# CAtlRegExp : match a string until a hexadecimal set

Tags: c++, regex, mfc

I am trying to take a string and use a regular expression to extract the string contents as well as the hexadecimal error code within the string.

For example :

`Failed to mount application "HexEditor" [0xA0042251]`

Which would result in the two groups as follows:

`Failed to mount application "HexEditor"`
    and    `0xA0042251`

I am using CAtlRegExp and the established rules which can be
[found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3zs4axe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

I've tried looking around stack overflow, and have found solutions using the concept of a "look around," but I don't believe CAtlRegExp supports this feature.

Thanks again.

Comment: You trying to extract `HexEditor` and `0xA0042251` ?

Comment: @apgp88 Sorry, should have clarified. I'm trying to obtain the entire string up until the hex code, so `Failed to mount application "HexEditor"` and `0xA0042251`

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

`^(.*?)\s+\[(0x[a-zA-F0-9]+)\]`

Please note I introduced a validation touch to this regex since hexadecimal values can only contain numbers and letters from `A` to `F`.

Your String 1 - `Failed to mount application "HexEditor"` - will be inside Group 1  and the hex value `0xA0042251` will be in Group 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex,

```
(.*?)\[(\w+)\]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rJ4xL3/1)

It uses the concept of [Group capture](http://regexone.com/lesson/11)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've never used CAtlRegExp, but ... cross fingers about the nested capture ...

```
// catlregexp_class.cpp
#include <afx.h>
#include <atlrx.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CAtlRegExp<> reUrl;
    // Two match groups: the whole string and the hex part.
    REParseError status = reUrl.Parse(
        "^({.*{0[xX]\\h+}.*})$" );

    if (REPARSE_ERROR_OK != status)
    {
        // Unexpected error.
        return 0;
    }

    CAtlREMatchContext<> mcUrl;
    if (!reUrl.Match(
"Failed to mount application \"HexEditor\" and 0xA0042251",
        &mcUrl))
    {
        // Unexpected error.
        return 0;
    }

    for (UINT nGroupIndex = 0; nGroupIndex < mcUrl.m_uNumGroups;
         ++nGroupIndex)
    {
        const CAtlREMatchContext<>::RECHAR* szStart = 0;
        const CAtlREMatchContext<>::RECHAR* szEnd = 0;
        mcUrl.GetMatch(nGroupIndex, &szStart, &szEnd);

        ptrdiff_t nLength = szEnd - szStart;
        printf_s("%d: \"%.*s\"\n", nGroupIndex, nLength, szStart);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output

0: "Failed to mount application "HexEditor" and 0xA0042251"
1: "0xA0042251"

Comment: i read the link to CAtlRegExp, and it looks like {} is the capture parenthesis, not () like in other kinds of regex.  Also, the entire match is not captured, unlike in other regex.  0 of the match collection is NOT the full match, it's the first capture group.